# Azure APIM 302 Moved temporarily error how to fix it?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management

Trying to make a policy for getting a bearer token trough a send-request sticking it in the Authorization header and then posting JSON data to the given back-end.

But when I test it within the test tab of Azure I always receive the same error:
[image]

Even when I add `<forward-request timeout="60" follow-redirects="60"/>` it does not work.
I also tried it without the follow-redirects which is defaulted to false but also no effect.

I am completly new to Azure so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="20" response-variable-name="bearerToken" mode="new">
            <set-url>{{AuthenticationServer}}</set-url>
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>Basic {{Base64encodedusernamepassword}}</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
              return "grant_type=client_credentials";
           }</set-body>
        </send-request>
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@("Bearer " + (String)((IResponse)context.Variables["bearerToken"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])</value>
        </set-header>
        <!--  Don't expose APIM subscription key to the backend. -->
        <!--<set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" /> -->
        <set-backend-service base-url="{{BaseURI}}" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request timeout="60" follow-redirects="true" />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: Yea the issue was fixed, the company providing my account did not give me VPN access. Which was needed to test the endpoint.

Comment: I don't know if it's your case but you'll also get this error if your APIM is an Internal Vnet  when before it was in an External Vnet.

Comment: Yea I am not sure how they set the Vnet up. But I am pretty sure it is an internal now so VPN fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the endpoint was behind a private VNet so getting VPN access fixed the issue.